# django database efficient querysets on two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am quite new to django - and I was wondering if I could use the ORM to make the below queries more efficiently:

```
# somewhere in views.py..
if slug is not None:
    slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
    pkid = FinalModel.objects.all().get(slug__exact=slug)
    queryset = queryset.filter(owner__exact=pkid.id)
    obj = queryset.get()
    return obj
```

So, basically, what I am doing is (to return an object), first: get the `pkid` using the slug in the url, then use this info (`pkid.id`) to get the correct full object using the queryset (which operates on a different model - which is `OnetToOne` keyed to the `FinalModel`) statement above.

So, in a nutshell, I am first extracting the `PK` using the `slug` (Model=FinalModel) and use this `PK` on another model (the `queryset` model) which is `OneToOne` keyed to the `FinalModel` (using the `owner` attribute).

I am not sure that using two such statements is efficient for the DB (I am no expert on this either) - and I was wondering if anyone could suggest how I could combine the two statements (`pkid` and `queryset`) to get the final object more efficiently.

Sorry if this is a django 101 question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have been easier to answer if you'd shown your models. But assuming `owner` is a ForeignKey from FinalModel to whatever model you want to get at the end, you can use the double-underscore syntax to do a JOIN:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(owner__slug=slug)
```

(Note you don't need to specify `exact`, it's the default.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this - that works perfectly!! I was wondering if I could ask you another question (probably not completely related to this). I was wondering what this statement does: `queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})` especially, what does `**{slug_field: slug}` construct mean here? Thanks so much for all your help - has certainly helped me understand better.

Comment: `**dict` is just a means of passing a dictionary as keyword arguments. That's useful because the keyword name itself can be a variable, as in your example, as well as the value.

Comment: Thanks a tonne. Solved all problems :) Marked your answer as correct!